# Call web services via JavaScript in a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web-services, fine-uploader

I am using the fine-uploader to allow multiple file uploads. The files are uploaded 1 by 1 by the fine-uploader library, and on the 'complete' event, which fires every time a file has uploaded successfully, I call a function that calls a web service and makes some updates to my database.

Potentially a user could update 100, or a 1000 files at a time.

My question is do i need to do anything specific to the JavaScript or Web services so that repeated requests do not cause a problem. I know that the $.ajax function is asynchronous by default, is this enough to ensure that problems don't occur?

Comment: Note that you will never have 100 or 1000 files uploading at once.  By default, Fine Uploader only sends 3 files at a time.  Even if you remove or change this limit, browsers natively limit the number of concurrent HTTP requests per endpoint host/domain.  

Also note that there is nothing magical about `$.ajax` - [it just delegates to `XMLHttpRequest`](http://blog.garstasio.com/you-dont-need-jquery/ajax/) which sends all requests asynchronously by default.  

It's not clear what "problems" you are worried about.  If you can elaborate, perhaps you can get some more specific answers.

Comment: The problems I am worried about are general, such as the uploader crashing or becoming unresponsive.

Answer (score 2):

You can call $.ajax as many times as you need to. jQuery will handle it just fine.

Also, is there a way you can update your database from the server-side at the time the file is uploaded? This way you would just have a single call to the server, thus greatly speeding up the entire file upload process since 1 call is much faster than 2.

Comment: I would caution you from calling `$.ajax` as many times as you need to.  Since browsers limit the number of concurrent requests per endpoint, you run the risk of holding up other requests elsewhere on the page.

Comment: @RayNicholus, correct you'll want to limit the number of concurrent requests to the same server. However, DavidB is talking about making these requests 1 at a time, so it shouldn't be a problem given there isn't anything else on the page make many requests simultaneously.

Comment: If he's simply sending the request when Fine Uploader fires an onComplete event, then there is no guarantee that there will only be 1 request sent at a time.  Also, we don't know anything about the rest of the page.

Comment: I could potentially combine the upload call and the database update together, my only real issue is that i am using a dedicated file handler and don't really want it to know about database connections etc. Thanks for the answer